# Javascript - Object in object access first parent's property

Tags: javascript

I have an object inside another object and I need to access the first parent's property. Here is my code.

```
var api = {

    apiBaseUrl: 'http://example.com/',

    sendRequest: function (url, method, data) {
        console.log('send request')
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: method,
            data: data
        })
    },

    /**
     * string topic, function callback
     */
    study: {
        getStudies: function () {
            var url = this.apiBaseUrl + 'studies';
            var method = 'GET';

            this.sendRequest(url, method);
        },
    };
};

api.study.getStudies()
```

In the function `api.study.getStudies()`, I want to acccess the variable `apiBaseUrl` and the function `sendRequest` of the `api` object, how can I do that ?

Comment: The issue here is that `this` points to `study` and not `api`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With what you've quoted, you only have a single object, so just use `api` where you currently have `this`. As the functions are closures over the context containing the `api` variable, they have access to the variable.

Note that the quoted code also has a syntax error.

So the changes are:

```
study: {
    getStudies: function () {
        var url = api.apiBaseUrl + 'studies'; // <== Here
        var method = 'GET';

        api.sendRequest(url, method);         // <== Here
    },
}                                             // <== Here (the ; was a syntax error)
```